# Is it possible to add style to default <p> tag in Quill?

Tags: quill, react-quill

My objective is to create a button in toolbar that add style to the default `<p>` tag where the cursor is. For example:

From `<p>Example</p>` to `<p style="color: white;">Example</p>` without nested format?

Now, my workaround is using a new custom blots which did pretty much the same thing like

`<p><custom style="color: white;">Example</custom><p>`

I literately have no idea how to do that as I'm new to quill. I've been spent few days studying quill/parchment documents but not 100% understand how it work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

see the [「ttypic」comment](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/3065):

And this is my code:

```
const Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
class MyBlock extends Block {
  static create() {
    const node = super.create();
    // Next, customize other functions
    node.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 0;');
    return node;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 14 with Primeng this worked great for me. I changed the p tag to div tag

```
import * as QuillNamespace from 'quill';

Quill: any = QuillNamespace;    
const Block = this.Quill.import('blots/block');
class DivBlock extends Block {}
DivBlock.tagName = 'DIV';
// true means we overwrite
this.Quill.register('blots/block', DivBlock, true);
```